# Django channels with azure web app and storage

Tags: python, django, azure, websocket, redis

I've been trying to setup a production enviornment with Azure web app and azure redis cache, for my django app.

In my browser I get this error in the console:

```
(index):157 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/ws/chat/hey/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

in my settings.py I have tried a couple different settings. The last one I can get to work with

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set("gg", "1234567")
print(cache.get("gg"))
```

where I can see the activity from the Redis Console on azure portal. But I am not able to use the backend 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' which I suspect I need.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION' : '<my_azure_redis>.redis.cache.windows.net:6379',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'PASSWORD': '<mypassword>',
            'DB': '1'
        },
    }
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'HOST': '<my_azure_redis>.redis.cache.windows.net',
            'PORT': '6379',
            'PASSWORD': '<mypassword>',
            'SSL' : False,
        }
    }
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': '%s:%s' % ("<my_azure_redis>.redis.cache.windows.net", 6379),
    'OPTIONS': {
        'PASSWORD': "<mypassword>",
        'DB': 0,
    }
  }
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = "django_azure_demo.routing.application"
```

javascript:

```
const socket = new WebSocket(
        'wss://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/chat/'
        + 'hey'
        + '/'
    );
```

routing.py:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/hey/', consumer.ChatConsumer),
]
```

asgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_azure_demo.settings')
application = get_asgi_application()
```

routing.py

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                    food.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
                )
            )
        )

})
```

This all works in development.

I had followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-python-get-started to get started with redis. And I were able to set and retrieve a variable from my redis storage.

I also opened for the 6379 port in azure cache for redis, to allow non SSL.

I'm at a blank here, and not sure where to go next. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Did u find a solution on implementing django channels in azure?

Comment: @saibhaskar nope. I gave up! :(

Comment: Did u find any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still wondering this is how you do it

store your credentials in a variable

```
myHostname = ""
myPassword = ""
```

and use this channel setting

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('rediss://:{password}@{hostname}:{port}'.format(
                password=myPassword,
                hostname=myHostname,
                port=6380
            ))],
        },
    },
}
```